# Is the function $\mathcal I: \{\text{algebraic sets}\} \to \{\text{radical ideals}\}$ well-defined when the field is not algebraically closed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

In Dummit/Foote, it is claimed that the function $\mathcal I$ is injective even when the base field is not algebraically closed. But I claim that this is not a function.

> > [image]

---

Take $k=\mathbb Q$ and consider $x^2+1 \in \mathbb Q[x]$. We have $\mathcal Z(x^2+1)=\varnothing = \mathcal Z(1)$ but $\sqrt (x^2+1) \ne \sqrt (1)$.

Is there an error here?

Comment: Please do *not* use images to convey mathematical information that is not present in the rest of the post. [See here for an explanation why this is bad practice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742). Use `\sqrt{x^2+1}` (curly brackets), not `\sqrt(x^2+1)`.

Answer (score 4):

Your post suggests that you think $\mathcal{I}$ is *defined* so that $\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{Z}(I)) = \mathrm{rad}(I)$ for all ideals $I$. This is not the definition of $\mathcal{I}$! Instead, this is a theorm about the relationship between $\mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{Z}$ over an algebraically closed field.

For any field $k$, given an affine algebraic set $X\subseteq k^n$, $\mathcal{I}(X)$ is defined to be the set of all polynomials in $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ which vanish on $X$. This is a radical ideal in $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, so $\mathcal{I}$ is obviously a function from affine algebraic sets to radical ideals.

In your example, $\mathcal{Z}(x^2+1) = \varnothing$, so $\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{Z}(x^2+1)) = \mathcal{I}(\varnothing) = (1) = \mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, since every polynomial vanishes on $\varnothing$ (vacuously). Also, $\mathcal{Z}(1) = \varnothing$, so $\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{Z}(1)) = \mathcal{I}(\varnothing) = (1) = \mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$.

All this shows is that the result $\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{Z}(I)) = \mathrm{rad}(I)$ can fail when the field is not algebraically closed.

Comment: In my post, $\mathcal I$ takes $\mathcal Z(x^2+1)$ and $\mathcal Z(1)$ to two different values even though $\mathcal Z(x^2+1)=\varnothing = \mathcal Z(1)$. How can it be well-defined?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Read again the definition of $\mathcal{I}$.

Comment: Are you considering the Example at the bottom of the image in my post?

Comment: @user46372819 Yes. I have updated my answer to address it

Answer (score 3):

All you're really saying is that $\mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{Z}$ aren't invertible for $k = \mathbb{Q}$.  That's fine.

The value $\mathcal{I}(\emptyset) = (1)$ is well-defined.

Comment: $\mathcal I$ takes $\mathcal Z(x^2+1)$ and $\mathcal Z(1)$ to two different values even though $\mathcal Z(x^2+1)=\varnothing = \mathcal Z(1)$. How can it be well-defined?

Comment: You might need to look at the definition of $\mathcal{I}$.  When $k$ is algebraically closed, we have $\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{Z}(I)) = \sqrt{I}$, but that's not the definition of $\mathcal{I}$.

Comment: Have you seen the Example at the bottom of the image?

Comment: Yes.  Nowhere does it say that necessarily $\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{Z}(I)) = \sqrt{I}$ when $k$ is not algebraically closed.  The _definitions_ of $\mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{Z}$ are found in a previous section (15.1 on pages 660 and 658 respectively, in my copy)